# Mongodb on Ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, installation

Is there any other document except for [that](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Ubuntu+and+Debian+packages) which explains how to install MongoDB on Linux? I get this error:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /etc/apt/secring.gpg --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10
gpg: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/libreadline.so.6: undefined symbol: PC
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved that error as described here:

```
ls /usr/local/lib

su
mkdir temp
mv /usr/local/lib/libreadline* temp
ldconfig
apt-get update

rm -rf /usr/local/lib/temp
```

from: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1484848

Answer (score 0):

I fought this problem from synaptic on down to gpg, only to find it was readline all along. My solution was somewhat simpler than building or patching.

in terminal:

ls /usr/local/lib

there was a bunch of readline libs in there (libreadline.so.BLAH-BLAH) so i:

su
mkdir temp
mv /usr/local/lib/libreadline* temp
ldconfig
apt-get update

and voila. went without a hitch. then i deleted my temporary directory (rm -rf /usr/local/lib/temp), exited su.