# Why do I get a Readline error when trying to start rails console?

Tags: ruby, rvm, readline, ruby-1.9, libreadline

UPDATE: I probably messed up my system while trying solutions found somewhere else. I started from scratch and Ruby 1.9.3 installed without a hitch. Now to try to get ree-1.8.7 to play nice alongside...

---

I'm trying to install Ruby 1.9.3 using RVM on Kubuntu (11.10 I believe). I've been having plenty of issues with Readline so far, but found the answer to all but this one.

I installed Ruby 1.9.3 this way:

```
rvm install 1.9.3
# Install of ruby-1.9.3-p0 - #complete 
cd ~/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p0/ext/readline/
~/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p0/ext/readline $ ../../ruby extconf.rb --with-editline-dir="/usr" --with-readline-dir="/usr"
# any other way of doing this resulted in simply readline not being loaded when trying to start the console
# I have libreadline6 and libreadline6-dev installed (and all the packages requested in `rvm requirements`
make install
# compiling readline.c                                                                                                                                                                                      
# linking shared-object readline.so                                                                                                                                                                         
# /usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 readline.so /home/mbillard/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux                                                                                    
# installing default readline libraries
```

So far everything looks to have run properly but when I try to start the console I get this error:

```
/home/mbillard/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/completion.rb:9:in `require': /home/mbillard/.rvm/usr/lib/libreadline.so.6: undefined symbol: UP - /home/mbillard/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/readline.so (LoadError)
  from /home/mbillard/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/completion.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
  from /home/mbillard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@taskman/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `require'
  from /home/mbillard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@taskman/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
  from /home/mbillard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@taskman/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:38:in `require'
  from /home/mbillard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@taskman/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:38:in `<top (required)>'
  from script/rails:6:in `require'
  from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I tried using `rvm install 1.9.3 --with-readline-dir="$rvm_path/usr"` and using `$rvm_path` when compiling Readline in the command above but those resulted in this error:

```
checking for tgetnum() in -lncurses... yes
checking for readline/readline.h... yes
checking for readline/history.h... yes
checking for readline() in -lreadline... no
checking for readline() in -ledit... no
checking for editline/readline.h... no
```

So, thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Not your exact error, but perhaps the answer to this question will help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760511/mongodb-on-ubuntu

Comment: @Brian thanks, but it didn't work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please read the output of:

```
rvm requirements
```

It will show you list of libraries you need to install to make good use of Ruby

After installing all the libs, clean rvm installed libs and reinstall Ruby:

```
rm -rf $rvm_path/usr
rvm reinstall 1.9.3
```

Comment: I already did install everything listed in `rvm requirements` as I wrote in my question, I'll check again just to be sure though.

Comment: updated, after rereading I found another issue, you had an installation of readline in rvm path, cleaning it will solve your problem (at least it should)

Comment: I need my installation of libreadline in $rvm_path because I also use ree-1.8.7 which requires that readline package.

Comment: it's what produces issues, on ubuntu readline is good from standard packages and you do not have to use RVM compiled version, just reinstall 1.8.7 also after removing .../usr

Comment: I tried removing everything from $rvm_path/usr, removing both my rubies (ree-1.9.7 and ruby-1.9.3), then reinstalling from there, but I still get the same error (and now ree-1.8.7 doesn't work anymore). Thanks for the tips though.

Comment: it's not possible to get exactyl the same problem as you have removed the `$rvm_path/usr` and the error was pointing to `/home/mbillard/.rvm/usr/lib/libreadline.so.6` either you missed to remove it or the error msg. changed, please show the new output

Comment: you're right, I must have reinstalled the packages after it failed. I tried the above but it fails when reinstalling, it complains about an error in openssl_missing.h `conflicting types for ‘HMAC_CTX_copy’`. I tried 2 other times, once with `--with-readline-dir=/usr/` and the second time I added `--with-openssl-dir=/usr/` with no success.

Comment: I think I have messed up my machine by trying all sorts of things, I think I'm gonna reinstall the OS.

Answer (score 5):

You need to install the readline development packages. (This is how my answer differs from the other existing one):

```
apt-get install libreadline-dev
```

After doing so, you can reinstall Ruby (as @mpapis already mentioned) and everything should work.

```
rvm reinstall 1.9.3
```

Comment: I already have libreadline6-dev installed, is there a difference?

Comment: I installed this package and it fix the problem. @mbillard, on my Ubuntu installation the following dependency packages were also installed along libreadline-dev (libncurses5-dev libreadline-dev libreadline6-dev libtinfo-dev)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. try

```
brew link readline --force
```

that worked for me.

I got the solution from here:

[Rails Console Not Loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12591585/rails-console-not-loading)