# Rails Console Not Loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When trying to start `rails console` I keep getting the following error

```
Users/rigelstpierre/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/completion.rb:9:in `require': dlopen(/Users/rigelstpierre/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.0/readline.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /Users/rigelstpierre/.rvm/usr/lib/libreadline.6.2.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/rigelstpierre/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.0/readline.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/rigelstpierre/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.0/readline.bundle
    from /Users/rigelstpierre/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/completion.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/rigelstpierre/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `require'
    from /Users/rigelstpierre/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/rigelstpierre/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:38:in `require'
    from /Users/rigelstpierre/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:38:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Any thoughts? Rails 3.2.2 application

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It could be that there are multiple versions of readline installed.

Try the following:

```
brew link readline --force
```

Comment: Tried that and still nothing.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. What did that command return? My suspicion is that there may be an issue with your readline installation.

Comment: I went through the blog post, and then ran 'brew link readline' and that created the symlink.
'/Users/rigelstpierre/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/completion.rb:9:in `require': dlopen(/Users/rigelstpierre/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.0/readline.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /Users/rigelstpierre/.rvm/usr/lib/libncurses.5.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/rigelstpierre/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.0/readline.bundle
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:'

Comment: I had to do: `brew link readline --force` to make it work. Thank you.

Answer (score 15):

I had this couple of days ago. You can try to reinstall/recompile your ruby. In my case problem appeared when **updating from El Capitan to Sierra**

so depending on your manager:

**RVM**

```
rvm reinstall 2.3.0
```

**Rbenv**

```
rbenv uninstall 2.3.0
rbenv install 2.3.0
```

**asdf**

```
asdf uninstall ruby 2.3.0
asdf install ruby 2.3.0
```

Comment: No worries. but dude, it took me a looong time to do this. I basically tried other solutions from this page and nothing worked....

Answer (score 15):

Looking elsewhere, none of the re-linking options worked.  It was suggested to redo the rvm installation (which seems onerous).  However, simply adding readline into the Gemfile works for me:

```
gem 'rb-readline'
```

Comment: Worked for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

It is because multiple versions of readline is installed (Could be because you ran `brew update` recently). What Ron said is right. You can fix it by running `brew link readline` or `brew link readline --force`.

If it still doesn't work, find which readline and move to readline folder then delete the version that you don't need (Or the ones that installed by running brew update). Then run `brew link readline` again.

Comment: this worked, deleted the newer version inside `/usr/local/Cellar/readline`, ran the above command and worked again!

Answer (score 5):

For me on macOS sierra, `brew link readline` or `brew link readline --force` does not work and I ran `brew update` recently. But `rails console` does work after I do as below:

`rvm reinstall 2.3.1`

Answer (score 3):

After reinstalling `readline`, I could still not able to load `rails console`.

However, reinstalling `ruby` did it for me.

```
rvm reinstall 1.9.3
```

PS: I'm on OSX El Capitan

Answer (score 1):

On macOS Sierra I was facing the same issue with homebrew and libreadline, 
I tried to do `brew link readline`, `brew link readline --force` and `brew update` 
but all in vain, then I found another solution that solved my issue.

There was a linking issue libreadline required by homebrew was unlinked and not able to link by `brew commands`

Creating a symbolic link solved my issue.

`ln -s /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.0.dylib /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib`

Try creating symbolic link. Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! "Run-this" answers are not useful without an explanation of why this will help.

Comment: Ok got it. will take care

Comment: @JoeC I agree. Answers with a minimal explanation should be enforced.

Comment: This did fix the issue for me though although it is without explanation.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the version numbers of readline were different, and I was missing `libreadline.7.dylib`. Linking and unlinking using Homebrew didn't help. The following did though:

```
~$ cd /usr/local/opt/readline/lib
/usr/local/opt/readline/lib$ ls -l
total 1448
-r--r--r--  1 ceasar  staff   40396 Mar 22 11:35 libhistory.8.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ceasar  staff      20 Dec 19 13:07 libhistory.8.dylib -> libhistory.8.0.dylib
-r--r--r--  1 ceasar  staff   45848 Dec 19 13:07 libhistory.a
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ceasar  staff      20 Dec 19 13:07 libhistory.dylib -> libhistory.8.0.dylib
-rw-r--r--  1 ceasar  staff  239260 Mar 22 11:35 libreadline.8.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ceasar  staff      21 Dec 19 13:07 libreadline.8.dylib -> libreadline.8.0.dylib
-r--r--r--  1 ceasar  staff  406384 Dec 19 13:07 libreadline.a
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ceasar  staff      21 Dec 19 13:07 libreadline.dylib -> libreadline.8.0.dylib
drwxr-xr-x  3 ceasar  staff      96 Mar 22 11:35 pkgconfig
/usr/local/opt/readline/lib$ ln -s libreadline.dylib libreadline.7.dylib
```