# rails console doesn't load due to libreadline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I have recently reinstalled ruby 2.1.2 like so since I wanted to install a gem (`ruby-debug-ide`)

```
sudo rvm reinstall 2.1.2 --disable-binary --with-gcc=gcc-4.2
```

Since then, I can't load my console using `bundle exec rails c`
due to the following error :

```
/Users/ohad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@aaa/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': dlopen(/Users/ohad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin13.0/readline.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: @@HOMEBREW_PREFIX@@/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/ohad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin13.0/readline.bundle
```

Tried `brew uninstall readline` and `brew install --build-from-source readline` which worked but didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails Console Not Loading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12591585/rails-console-not-loading)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Ran across this today, to solve it I did:

`brew rm -f readline`

`brew install readline`

`brew link readline --force`

Hope it helps.

EDIT: I recently ran into this problem again (after downgrading Ruby) since I wrote this, and I now prefer @califrench's solution from the comments below:

`ln -s /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.dylib /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib`

Comment: worked for me too, thanks! although when running `brew doctor` it tells me to unlink it? I think that is what caused the error to come up in the first place, strange..

Comment: For me `cp /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.dylib /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib` did the trick. Looks like rails 4.2.6 was looking for `libreadline.6` instead of `libreadline`. I probably should have symlinked it to be honest though. So `ln -s /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.dylib /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib` is more appropriate. hope this helps others who are still stuck!

Comment: I've found @califrench's solution to work after finding `rails c` was broken after upgrading to Sierra.

Comment: no idea why this suddenly started happening this morning but califrench's solution worked for me when none of the others did.... thanks!

Comment: Didn't work for me... Thanks @califrench, your solution was more simple and it works :D

Comment: Thanks @califrench. This worked for me too like most others. I am adding this as community wiki answer. You are still welcome to add this as your own answer, when you get time.

Comment: Thanks @califrench, OP's answer didn't work for me, the comment did. Might want to post it as an answer :)

Comment: and run `rails console` after `spring stop`

Answer (score 78):

> Based on a comment on the accepted answer with more up-votes than the answer, this seems to be the most popular solution.

Looks like rails 4.2.6 was looking for `libreadline.6` instead of `libreadline`. So just need to create a symlink.

```
ln -s /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.dylib \
/usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib
```

Hope this helps others who are still stuck!

Comment: Thanks for posting my solution. I have gotten good feedback and was about to post it. I up-voted this!

Comment: @califrench, it's a community wiki, please do some edit to make it as you like and then you will be added as a contributor too. (It's kinda injustice not to see your name here!)

Comment: Solved my issue as well!  I'm using Rails v4.2.4. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Califrench and Tareq!
I up voted this answer and downvoted the answers that are showing up higher in the rankings (but not as helpful). Unfortunately, I don't have enough rep to change the public totals. Hoping future readers will also place similar votes.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! In my case, just needed to change `...libreadline.6.dylib` to `...libreadline.7.dylib`

Answer (score 52):

I was able to resolve the same problem by reinstalling Ruby.
On the Homebrew side reinstalling readline (even from source) didn't help.

I'm using RVM so this sorted it for me:

`rvm reinstall 2.3.1`

I think Homebrew may have pulled in readline v7 recently for some other package, which I suspect could well be the culprit.

Comment: Thanks — that fixed it. For rbenv users, the rbenv equivalent is `rbenv install -f 2.3.1`.

Comment: Same here! re-installing 2.3.1 fixed it for me.

Comment: I do not meet the issue when working in terminal, but only in [RubyMine](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/2016.3/running-rails-console.html) (???). And re-installing fixed it (???).

Comment: I've seen situations where RubyMine SDK points to an out of date/wrong RVM gemset. Most typically when I upgrade the global default Ruby version.
I'd suggest checking the SDK

Comment: Was having issues running knife commands for ChefDK and this fixed it.

Comment: Worked for me, Ruby 2.3.0, Rails 4.2.7, RubyMine 2017.3.1.  Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

After getting a lot of positive feedback on my comment on @mauro_oto's post, I thought I'd post this as an answer:

> For me `cp /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.dylib /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib` did the trick. Looks like rails 4.2.6 was looking for libreadline.6 instead of libreadline. I probably should have symlinked it to be honest though. So `ln -s /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.dylib /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib` is more appropriate. hope this helps others who are still stuck!

Answer (score 16):

Adding `gem 'rb-readline'` to my `Gemfile` fixed this problem for me. See https://github.com/ConnorAtherton/rb-readline.

Answer (score 9):

None of all this worked for me. I am using osx sierra. This what worked for me.

```
ln -s /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.0.dylib /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib
```

Hope this helps someone out there.

Answer (score 6):

My ENV: Ruby: 2.2.1, Rails: 4.2.1, macOS Sierra 10.12.4;

The below command works for me and my colleague:

`ln -s /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.0.dylib /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib`

Answer (score 5):

This solved my problem:

Replace libreadline.{version}.dylib with the version you are getting error for:

```
ln -s /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.dylib /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib
```

Comment: this is the answer

Answer (score 2):

On OSX using homebrew, you can specify which readline version is active.  e.g.

`brew switch readline 6.3.8`

(it's likely installed in `/usr/local/Cellar/readline/` )

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing a similar problem but with more updated versions. The error I had was:

```
dlopen(/Users/juanjo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin18/readline.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/juanjo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin18/readline.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/juanjo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin18/readline.bundle
```

The important part is `Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib`

Looking at `/usr/local/opt/readline/lib/` I saw I had installed `libreadline.8.dylib`, not 7.

To solve my problem, guided by the other answers, I had to do the following:

`ln -s /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.8.dylib /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib`

In other words:
`ln -s /.../[libreadline you have] /.../[libreadline you need]`.