# How Do I Correct An Error with rails console command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, ruby-on-rails-4.2, rails-console

When I'm in the root directory of my Rails app I can successfully execute `rails server`. However when I try to do `rails console` or `rails c` I get the following error.

```
[myrailsapp (master)]$ rails c
/Users/myuserid/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/completion.rb:10:in `require': dlopen(/Users/myuserid/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15/readline.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/myuserid/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15/readline.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/myuserid/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15/readline.bundle
    from /Users/myuserid/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/completion.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/myuserid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@mygemset/gems/railties-4.2.5.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `require'
    from /Users/myuserid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@mygemset/gems/railties-4.2.5.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/myuserid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@mygemset/gems/railties-4.2.5.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:123:in `require'
    from /Users/myuserid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@mygemset/gems/railties-4.2.5.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:123:in `require_command!'
    from /Users/myuserid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@mygemset/gems/railties-4.2.5.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:58:in `console'
    from /Users/myuserid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@mygemset/gems/railties-4.2.5.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/myuserid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@mygemset/gems/railties-4.2.5.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I have done web searches but I have not found any solutions for this type of error.

Comment: Check the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591527/rails-console-doesnt-load-due-to-libreadline

Comment: Add this as an answer and I will upcheck it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`brew rm -f readline`

`brew install readline`

`brew link readline --force`

Reference link: [rails console doesn't load due to libreadline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591527/rails-console-doesnt-load-due-to-libreadline)

Comment: Thanks! I did this and was able to execute the rails console as before.

Comment: @FilipBartuzi When in doubt, you force ;)

Answer (score 3):

In my case a reinstall with rvm fixed the error

```
rvm reinstall 2.3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

edit: ok run this

```
sudo install_name_tool -change libreadline.6.dylib 
/usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib
/Users/myuserid/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15/readline.bundle

sudo install_name_tool -change libreadline.6.dylib 
/usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib
/Users/myuserid/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15/readline.bundle
```

to remove dir from old references