# rails c not working in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, command-line, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-console

On using the command in terminal inside a rails 5 application

```
rails c
```

the error thrown is given bellow. I have no idea what this means in a similar question here that for which the solution was to use spring stop. I have tried that too but no it still gave the same error. it would be great if somebody can point out the mistake here.

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 6457
/Users/AmanChawla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require': dlopen(/Users/AmanChawla/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15/readline.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/AmanChawla/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15/readline.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/AmanChawla/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15/readline.bundle
    from /Users/AmanChawla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    from /Users/AmanChawla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/AmanChawla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/AmanChawla/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/completion.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/AmanChawla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/AmanChawla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    from /Users/AmanChawla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/AmanChawla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/AmanChawla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/AmanChawla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/AmanChawla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    from /Users/AmanChawla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/AmanChawla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/AmanChawla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:138:in `require_command!'
    from /Users/AmanChawla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /Users/AmanChawla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/AmanChawla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/AmanChawla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/AmanChawla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    from /Users/AmanChawla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/AmanChawla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/AmanChawla/Desktop/NewApp/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/AmanChawla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    from /Users/AmanChawla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
    from /Users/AmanChawla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/AmanChawla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    from /Users/AmanChawla/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/AmanChawla/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Have you updated HomeBrew? and / Or Have you updates to Mac OSX Sierra? This error is most likely caused from updating homebrew as it has been patched for Sierra

Comment: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib is the issue

Comment: How do i fix this?

Comment: i need to know what you have updated

Comment: Please check my answer(accepted) here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37738934/how-do-i-correct-an-error-with-rails-console-command/37739110#37739110

Comment: Read my answer. Try it before you start messing with soft-links and other suggested answers.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I recently had this problem when I updated HomeBrew, I'm also working with rails 5 and found this solution and it worked for me:

```
ln -s /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.0.dylib /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/mcshakes/c87e8adda174c73be354094800b9756d

**UPDATE**

For readline 8 and newer versions, follow the answer given by @Cody Elhard

Comment: Works! Ruby 2.5.0, Rails 5.1.4 os/x

Comment: Or it could be: `ln -s /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.8.dylib /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib`

Comment: If you have readline 8 you will need to do `ln -s /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.8.0.dylib /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib`

Comment: Can this be considered a fix? Fixing a pointer to non-existent file by mimicking that file hardly seems like a solution. Rather a quick patch. Is there a way to make it point to the correct file?

Answer (score 22):

As a general approach if this error occurred due to updating readline with homebrew

New version can be found by reading the output of `brew install readline`

My output: `readline 8.0.0 is already installed and up-to-date`

Old version can be found by load error

My error (Note the 7): `Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib (LoadError)`

```
ln -s new_version/path/to/readline original_version/path/to/readline
```

In my case my command was

```
ln -s /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.8.0.dylib /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib
```

Comment: Worked for me after a strange bug with my Macbook, thanks

Comment: My symptoms started showing up after a `brew cleanup`.  This solved it!

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining how to think this through. That worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 10):

I fixed this issue by simply adding this gem   `gem 'rb-readline'` and running bundle.

[rb-readline](https://rubygems.org/gems/rb-readline/versions/0.5.3)

Answer (score 2):

This is a standard fix to this issue try this.. It should get you going

```
brew rm -f readline

brew install readline

brew link readline --force
```

here is a reference link [rails console doesn't load due to libreadline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591527/rails-console-doesnt-load-due-to-libreadline)

Answer (score 0):

Another issue might be which version of ruby is in your path - double check that as well.

```
ruby -v
ls -la `which ruby`
```

then check your PATH