# Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I try to run my `rails c` but for some reason, I get this error:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/166713e8cde860fb188a8dffb98a1563

```
ᐅ rails c
Running via Spring preloader in process 6609
/Users/zulhilmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@useradmin/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': dlopen(/Users/zulhilmi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15/readline.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/zulhilmi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15/readline.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/zulhilmi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15/readline.bundle
    from /Users/zulhilmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@useradmin/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /Users/zulhilmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@useradmin/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/zulhilmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@useradmin/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/zulhilmi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/completion.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/zulhilmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@useradmin/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/zulhilmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@useradmin/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /Users/zulhilmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@useradmin/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/zulhilmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@useradmin/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/zulhilmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@useradmin/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/zulhilmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@useradmin/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/zulhilmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@useradmin/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /Users/zulhilmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@useradmin/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/zulhilmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@useradmin/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/zulhilmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@useradmin/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:123:in `require_command!'
    from /Users/zulhilmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@useradmin/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:58:in `console'
    from /Users/zulhilmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@useradmin/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/zulhilmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@useradmin/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/zulhilmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@useradmin/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/zulhilmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@useradmin/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /Users/zulhilmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@useradmin/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/zulhilmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@useradmin/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/zulhilmi/hello_gold/cws/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/zulhilmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@useradmin/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/zulhilmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@useradmin/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
    from /Users/zulhilmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@useradmin/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/zulhilmi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@useradmin/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/zulhilmi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/zulhilmi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>’
```

What should I do now?

Comment: this question has been answered here already, See this Link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40435824/rails-c-not-working-in-rails-5/40435891#40435891 I answered it in our slack group as well.

Answer (score 237, accepted):

This command fix my problem:

```
ln -s /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.0.dylib /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib
```

OR

```
ln -s /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.8.0.dylib /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib
```

I wrote a Gist about this problem [here](https://gist.github.com/zulhfreelancer/47efc39584cb9f006da43c41c014e03a). There are many people sharing their solutions there too.

Comment: This may sound obvious but if the command doesn't work verbatim, change the versions to be the expected version and whatever is closest in the directory. My machine was expecting version 6 and I had version 7.

Comment: For me i had to change a bit - `ln -s /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.8.0.dylib /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib`

Comment: `ln -s /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.8.0.dylib /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib` can be a solution too

Comment: Any explanations ?

Comment: `ln -s /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.8.0.dylib /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib` I think you need to check which is installed at `/usr/local/opt/readline/lib` and then link that to `libreadline.6.dylib`.  In my case I needed to link 6 to 8. In the answer @Zulhilmi linked 6 to 7.

Answer (score 63):

Add this gem to your Gemfile and run `bundle install`:

```
gem 'rb-readline'
```

Comment: Gem is implementation of readline in ruby instead of C which is not so good probably.

Comment: Worked great.  Expedient yet conservative.  No symlinks to forget are there, no installs that might create other problems.

Answer (score 18):

I had the same underlying issue, which also occurred after a Mac OSX update. My problem manifested using psql:

```
>> psql --help

dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/psql
  Reason: image not found
```

OK, so this is telling me that it's expecting `libreadline.7.dylib` in `/usr/local/opt/readline/lib`. When I browse that directory, I can see I have `libreadline.8.0.dylib`:

```
>> ls -l /usr/local/opt/readline/lib

total 1448
 libhistory.8.0.dylib
 libhistory.8.dylib -> libhistory.8.0.dylib
 libhistory.a
 libhistory.dylib -> libhistory.8.0.dylib
 libreadline.8.0.dylib
 libreadline.8.dylib -> libreadline.8.0.dylib
 libreadline.a
 libreadline.dylib -> libreadline.8.0.dylib
```

I made the assumption that emulating `libreadline.7.dylib` by using symlinking to `libreadline.8.0.dylib` could resolve my problem:

```
>> ln -s /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.8.0.dylib /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib
```

Which makes my call to `psql` work again, but doesn't address how the problem started in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

I installed the ruby of same version over again. Then the error message is gone now. I use macbook and homebrew.

```
$ rbenv install 2.3.8
rbenv: /Users/klee/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8 already exists
continue with installation? (y/N) y
ruby-build: use openssl from homebrew
Downloading ruby-2.3.8.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.3/ruby-2.3.8.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-2.3.8...
ruby-build: use readline from homebrew
Installed ruby-2.3.8 to /Users/klee/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8
```

Comment: Happened to me on `2.1.10`. Fixed by reinstalling it.

Comment: This seems like the right approach (better than assuming v8 of a library is compatible with v7). For rvm: `rvm reinstall ruby-2.6.2`

Answer (score 4):

Just recompiled ruby version using updated readline from homebrew and it works like a charm.

```
rbenv install $(rbenv version-name)
```

Answer (score 2):

i was having the same type of issue but it was due to the fact that my awk was linked to gawk leading to using the wrong lib

this worked for me

`brew unlink gawk`

Answer (score 1):

simply reinstalling ruby 2.3.0 fixed my problem on macos
I use rbenv
`rbenv install 2.3.0` did the trick

Answer (score 0):

In my case **readline** was installed but not linked after a MacOS migration. This command fixed it:

```
brew link --force readline
```

Answer (score 0):

worked for me on Mac

following here https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/5799
to update bash, run:

```
brew upgrade bash
```