# rails 5, rbenv - rails console doesn't start - Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console, rbenv

When I run "rails c" command in terminal, somehow it doesn't start rails console and throws the error. I am running rails 5.2.2 with rbenv.

```
rails c
```

It throws the following error.

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 13912
Traceback (most recent call last):
    50: from -e:1:in `<main>'
    49: from /Users/wemteq/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    48: from /Users/wemteq/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    47: from /Users/wemteq/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `load'
    ...
     7: from /Users/wemteq/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
     6: from /Users/wemteq/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
     5: from /Users/wemteq/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
     4: from /Users/wemteq/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
     3: from /Users/wemteq/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     2: from /Users/wemteq/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
     1: from /Users/wemteq/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/wemteq/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require': dlopen(/Users/wemteq/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin17/readline.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/wemteq/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin17/readline.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/wemteq/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin17/readline.bundle
```

It worked a week ago, but not working now. Any ideas?

Comment: this answer probably can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/40682002/938947

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found 2 solutions from some researching.

```
Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib (LoadError)
```

1. **libreadline.7.dylib** is missing, so linking **libreadline.8.0.dylib** to **libreadline.7.dylib** worked for me.

   ln -s /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.8.0.dylib /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib

> **libreadline** version might be different. You can browse available files in **/usr/local/opt/readline/lib/** directory.

2. **rb-readline** gem in development group would fix this problem.

   gem 'rb-readline'