# Gems not being installed to correct directory using rbenv

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, rbenv

When I try to run `rails console` it blows up and gives me this error:

```
  Referenced from: /Users/masonry/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15/readline.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/masonry/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15/readline.bundle
```

Unfortunately, [reinstalling and relinking readline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25810042/5381605) with homebrew does not do the trick for me.

I've tried including `rb-readline` in my Gemfile but still not working.

The only way to fix this problem is to completely nuke ruby and reinstall... which takes a long time and is tedious.

I have a suspicion that the source of this problem may be that my gems are being installed to an incorrect directory.  Here's where they are being installed:

```
→ gem env home
/Users/masonry/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
```

I am using ruby 2.3.1, so why do I have `lib/gems/2.3.0`? Maybe that's the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling and reinstalling ruby 2.3.1 worked for me:

```
→ rbenv uninstall 2.3.1
→ rbenv install 2.3.1
→ rbenv global 2.3.1 #or rbenv local 2.3.1
→ rbenv rehash
```

rbenv doesn't have a fancy reinstall command like rvm.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and it was because i had rvm installed with rbenv. i had to uninstall rvm and uninstall ruby then reinstalled ruby and rails entirely. not sure if you have rvm. but i hope this helps or gives you a clue.