# Rails Console won't run (console error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to run rails console command but it throw error everytime I run it.
Here is the error I get :

```
Loading development environment (Rails 5.1.4)
D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rbreadline.rb:6090:in `delete': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentErr
or)
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rbreadline.rb:6090:in `alloc_history_entry'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rbreadline.rb:6123:in `add_history'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/readline.rb:368:in `<<'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/ext/save-history.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in load_history'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/ext/save-history.rb:76:in `each'

        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/ext/save-history.rb:76:in `block in load_history'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/ext/save-history.rb:75:in `open'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/ext/save-history.rb:75:in `load_history'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/ext/save-history.rb:65:in `extended'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/ext/save-history.rb:21:in `extend'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/ext/save-history.rb:21:in `init_save_history'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/ext/save-history.rb:45:in `save_history='
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/context.rb:91:in `initialize'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb.rb:426:in `new'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb.rb:426:in `initialize'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb.rb:383:in `new'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb.rb:383:in `start'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:6
2:in `start'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:1
7:in `start'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:9
7:in `perform'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
        from D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I've tried to reinstall/reinstall and clean every version of ruby with no success. I use Ruby 2.3.3 and rails 5.1.4.
Thanks

Comment: Run command `bundle update` & check again.

Comment: @Salil Thanks for your answer but it still throw the same error.

Comment: Make sure you are not pasting non-UTF-8 chars into console. Just type `rails c` 7 check. also ref :- https://github.com/ConnorAtherton/rb-readline/issues/139

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on Windows(I'm assuming since you have `D:/`):

Try installing `rb-readline` gem in your `development` group. That's the easiest way for solving readline issues.

There are other [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591527/rails-console-doesnt-load-due-to-libreadline) as well if that doesn't work.